# Android display multiple images from Gallery

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery, android-memory

I am trying to display multiple images from Gallery. For that I am using [MultipleImagePick](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick) library to select multiple images from Gallery. My problem is, when displaying the selected images in image view, am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Here is the log

```
11-07 15:20:23.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 15:20:23.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2679): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-07 15:20:23.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-07 15:20:23.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:650)
11-07 15:20:23.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:389)
11-07 15:20:23.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:449)
```

I am using below code to display image in imageView

```
    Bitmap bitmapOriginal = null;
    Bitmap bitmapsimplesize = null;
    ImageView imageView;
    File imageFile;

for (String string : all_path) {
    imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageFile = new File(string); 
        if(imageFile.exists()){
            bitmapOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            bitmapsimplesize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOriginal,200, 200, true);
            bitmapOriginal.recycle();
            imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize);
        } else {
            Log.d("@@##", "image not exist");
        }
        imageHoler.addView(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Where are you testing this code on emulator or device?

Comment: @AmitGupta Am testing this code in Samsung S3

Comment: Scale down the image before loading to Imageview [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: @AmitGupta thanks for your response, I fixed my problem by Scale down the bitmap.